# How to pass an array of object as parameters in Restangular?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have no idea how i can pass an array of object in Restangular. I've read their documentation. I found that they provided such as customGET, customPOST etc. But, i didn't see the right example that related to my case. For now, i want it to get data from an API that needs params as its filter.

**1) Params**

```
var filter = {
  category: 1,
  page: 1,
  product: 20,
  price_range: ['bt',1,150]
}
```

**2) Services**

```
getRawList: function(filter) {
   return rawProducts.customGET('',filter).then(function(response) {
      return response;
   });
},
```

What i got was an Internal Server Error. Any idea how to tackle this error ?

Comment: Since you are trying to pass an object, it has to be POST method. Using GET is  not a proper way.

Comment: @RNS .. i want to retrieve data NOT to post it

Comment: I got your point that you are trying to retrieve data but passing an object like above to retrieve data is not a best method to do, instead you can pass an id to retrieve..

Comment: for eg. like return Restangular.all('someAPI?id='+id).customGET() ;

Comment: @RNS .. i'm not trying to retrieve a specific data. I want to get a group of data that has price between 1 to 150 dollar.

Comment: sir , trying to send object in a request is not possible in sending GET request. you should send your request and params using POST request.

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi .. it is just a params as a filter to get some data

Comment: yes , but you can't send params in GET request. send POST request

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi .. i want to get data, not to post / save data

Comment: post request is a kind of REQUESTS and is irrelevant to getting or setting data. sending params means posting params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string*. So, on this situation i need to convert the array property to string (which is price_range) before send it to the server as filter. This code solved my question.

```
getRawList: function(filter) {
   return rawProducts.customGET('',{
              category: filter.category,
              page: filter.page,
              product: filter.product,
              price_range: JSON.stringify(filter.price_range)
          }).then(function(response) {
      return response;
   });
}
```